# How to activate a new dialog in micro soft bot framework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, botframework, chatbot

I am creating a bot using a micro soft bot framework. In the root dialog, there is a method choiceReceivedAsync which calls another .cs file which is products.cs. In products.cs there is messageReceivedasync and it calls another .cs file which is plumbing.cs. The code in the messageReceivedasync in plumbing.cs is not executing. The code in StartAsync is executing but not in the messageReceivedasync in plumbing.cs.

Please help me

[message controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DxAr.png)

[Rootdialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9PpO.png)

[product.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hknc2.png)

[plumbingcategory.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80N2K.png)

[I am getting sorry, my bot code is having an issue. It should display the prompt in messagereceivedasync in plumbingcategory.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSG41.png)

Comment: Can you post the code from some or all of the dialogs so we can see what you have done and try to understand where things aren't working?

Comment: posted the code of dialogs and controller

Comment: hua, the issue, is your posting code as images (which is better than no code), images are hard to understand and troubleshoot. try editing your question with code and error messages directly put in the question. avoid images if possible to get better and faster responses.